# Pandas pivot_table with columns as horizon

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a dataframe like so:

```
first_dt     dt          val
2023-01-01   2023-01-02  1
2023-01-01   2023-01-02  1
2023-01-01   2023-01-03  1
...
2023-01-02   2023-01-03  1
2023-01-02   2023-01-04  1
```

You should note that `dt` is never less than `first_dt`.  I would like to reshape to a `pivot_table` like the following

```
first_dt    horizon_1  horizon_2  horizon_3
2023-01-01  2          1          0
2023-01-02  1          1          0
```

Initially, I thought I would do the following

```py
pandas.pivot_table(df, index='first_dt', columns='dt', values='val', aggfunc=np.sum)
```

However, this doesn't scale well when I have years of data when I only want a handful of horizons (e.g. 3, 7, etc).

Any thoughts about how to dynamically count `dt` over the `first_dt` time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert your data to datetime, compute the day difference (horizon), then pivot:

```
df['first_dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['first_dt'])
df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt'])

(df.assign(horizon=lambda x: x['dt'].sub(x['first_dt']).div(pd.Timedelta('1D')).astype(int))
   .query('horizon < 7') # query
   .pivot_table(index='first_dt', columns='horizon', values='val', aggfunc='sum')
)
```

Or similarly with `pd.crosstab`:

```
pd.crosstab(
    df['first_dt'],
    pd.to_datetime(df['dt']).sub(pd.to_datetime(df['first_dt']))
      .div(pd.Timedelta('1D')).astype(int)
      .loc[lambda x: x<7],
    df['val'],
    aggfunc='sum'
)
```

Output:

```
horizon     1  2
first_dt        
2023-01-01  2  1
2023-01-02  1  1
```

Comment: One follow up regarding my question on scaling, would there be a way to limit the horizon to something like 7 if some day differences are greater than 7?